# Mendeleev periodic table

Tags: periodic-table

[image]
Mendeleev accurately predicted the properties of gallium(eka aluminium). In his justification of properties he says(according to image given) the melting point of the element would be low. What could have been his insight considering the fact that melting points of  aluminium and indium are 660.3°C and 156.6°C respectively?

Comment: What do **you** think his insight was?

Comment: All I could think of is that it's melting point should be intermediate to that of aluminium and indium

Comment: Actually it's m.p. is lowest in the group not intermediate, but "low m.p." could be applied maybe even to Al.

Comment: I know that it has the lowest melting point in the group ,but in Mendeleev's case he would not have encountered the element right?

Comment: Sorry if the question was too basic, but all I was wondering was what Mendeleev was thinking when he mentioned low melting point of "eka-aluminium" ?Also was it relative to all other elements of the periodic table or pertaining only to the particular group?